# How to create a table using smarty/PHP?

Tags: php, smarty

I've been working on this all day and have tried every possible solution I could find but nothing seems to be working.  Here's a copy of my code (using Smarty template system):

```
<tr><td style="border-top: none;">

 <table>
    <tr><th colspan="7">TITLE OF THE TABLE</th></tr>

    {foreach from=$data.history item=tmp name=item}
            <tr><td colspan="1" class='{cycle name=color values="odd,even"}'>{$tmp->history}</td></tr>
    {/foreach}

 </table>

</td><tr>
```

If you looks in the `foreach` statement you'll see that I'm trying to create a new `td` for each piece of information.  This is actually working.  However, the problem is that it's not spanning them in the table like I want it to do.

I want each `td` to have its own column and for there to be a maximum of 7 columns.  As of right now, there's only one column showing and every is just split between rows.

Ideally, I want there to be 7 columns per row, even if some of them have to be empty because there's not enough data to pull.  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Did you tried to put `<tr>` out of `foreach`?

Comment: It doesn't sound like you should be using a table at all, since you don't seem to have tabular data. Sounds like you're merely using tables for layout purposes, which has been frowned upon for the past decade or so. Instead you probably want to use CSS to `float` your elements and give them a width of 1/7th each, so they'll arrange themselves in 7 items per line.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a final `</tr>`

```
<tr><td style="border-top: none;">

 <table>
    <tr><th colspan="7">TITLE OF THE TABLE</th></tr>

    {foreach from=$data.history item=tmp name=item}
            <tr><td colspan="1" class='{cycle name=color values="odd,even"}'>{$tmp->history}</td></tr>
    {/foreach}

 </table>

</td><tr>
      ^^^ ------------> should be </tr>
```